# Accessing a range of the first element of a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

Somewhat a python/programming newbie here.

I am trying to access a specified range of tuples from a list of tuples, but I only want to access the first element from the range of tuples. The specified range is based on a pattern I am looking for in a string of text that has been tokenized and tagged by nltk. My code:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

text = "It is pretty good as far as driveway size is concerned, otherwise I would skip it"
tokenized = word_tokenize(text)
tagged = pos_tag(tokenized)

def find_phrase():
    counter = -1
    for tag in tagged:
        counter += 1
        if tag[0] == "as" and tagged[counter+6][0] == "concerned":
            print tagged[counter:counter+7]

find_phrase()
```

Printed output:

`[('as', 'IN'), ('far', 'RB'), ('as', 'IN'), ('driveway', 'NN'), ('size', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('concerned', 'VBN')]`

What I actually want:

`['as', 'far', 'as', 'driveway', 'size', 'is', 'concerned']`

Is it possible to modify the my line of code `print tagged[counter:counter+7]` to get my desired printed output?

Comment: FYI whenever you find yourself writing a counter variable that just gets incremented in a loop, you should probably be using `enumerate` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
result, _ = zip(*find_phrase())
print result
```

Comment: that works great, but I have no idea how it works. Zip I am familiar with, but I have never seens a variable being declared with a trailing comma and an underscore `result, _`. What is going on there, or could you point me to some documentation about it?

Comment: @Darren it's just a valid variable name.  By common convention, naming a variable `_` means 'I'm not using this.'  Look up "tuple unpacking" if you don't understand how two things are being assigned to on the left hand side.

Comment: ah sorry, i was away from keyboard and roippi explained all. Thanks @roippi.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest method uses a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This statement creates a list from the first element of every tuple in your list:

```
print [tup[0] for tup in tagged[counter:counter+7]]
```

Or just for fun, if the tuples are always pairs, you could flatten the list (using any method you like) and then print every second element with the *step* notation of python's [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) notation:

```
print list(sum(tagged[counter:counter+7], ()))[::2]
```

Or use `map` with the [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) function, which calls the `__getitem__()` method to retrieve the 0th index of every tuple in your list:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print map(itemgetter(0), tagged[counter:counter+7])
```

Anything else? I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried zip?
also 
item[0] for item in name